# Qt Creator and Git: No configured push destination

Tags: c++, git, qt-creator

I keep trying to push a local repo to a remote repo and I keep getting "No configured push destination."

Comment: `git remote -v` gives what kind of output?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix the problem using Qt creator so I ended up realizing that I wasn't committing a certain branch.

```
git push reponame master
```

did the trick

Comment: If you want to set `reponame/master` as the default push location you should add the `-u` flag.